# SQL Server: invalid object name in query execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to execute an Insert statement, but keep getting a `Invalid object name` error.

Here's my code:

```
public string addNewComment(int userID, int pageID, string title, string comment)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.nokernok_kommentarer (userID, pageID, commentTitle, comment) " +
    "VALUES ("+ userID +", "+ pageID +", '"+ title +"', '"+ comment +"')";

    adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    //ExecuteNonQuery retuens number of rows affected
    int numRows = adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return numRows.ToString();
}
```

And here is my error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid object name
>   'dbo.nokernok_kommentarer'. at
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) at
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) at
>        System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at
>        System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async) at
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean
>   sendToPipe) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at
>        development.DAL.nokernokDAL.addNewComment(Int32
>   userID, Int32 pageID, String title,
>   String comment) in 
>        C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\naaf\DAL\nokernok.cs:line
>   49

Can anyone help me figure out why I get this error?

**UPDATE**

I should be using the correct database, because the following query works:

```
    public DataSet getSchools(string countyCode)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM nokernok_skoler WHERE kommunekode LIKE '" + countyCode.Substring(0, 2) + "%' ORDER BY enhetsnavn";
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

My connection string looks like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

// class constructor
public nokernokDAL()
{
    connection.ConnectionString = EPiServer.Global.EPConfig["EPsConnection"].ToString();
    connection.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're probably in the wrong database.  Include an initial catalog in your connection string:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; ...
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or specify a three part name:

```
INSERT INTO myDataBase.dbo.nokernok_kommentarer
            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @Steven: What does `select  SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) from sys.tables where name = 'nokernok_kommentarer'` return?

Comment: It returns `dbo`. Uh oh... hang on... testing something here.

Comment: @Steven: Then the `.dbo.` part is right.  Have you tried to use the three part name?  To find the database name use `select DB_NAME()`

Comment: I think I found the problem. I had created the table in an old DB which I'm not using any more. Thus the new table was never in the correct DB.... :-/

Comment: @Steven - sounds like my "you're connecting to the *database* you think you're connecting to?" answer is pretty close then. The number of times I've made exactly the same mistake, aargh! :)

Comment: Well, I was actually **connecting** to the right database. I just had created the table in the wrong database. Oh well, half day gone trying to figure out what was wrong.... now to figure out why my query is triggered twice (and the data is inserted twice).....

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, it would appear that the table `dbo.nokernok_kommentarer` doesn't exist in your database, or it isn't a table and is thus not updatable.

Have you checked that:

- You're connecting to the *server* you think you're connecting to?
- You're connecting to the *database* you think you're connecting to?
- You're specifiying the correct catalog (or whatever it's currently called =) i.e. Are you sure it should be `dbo.` and not `somethingElse.`?
- The table `dbo.nokernok_kommentarer` exists?

If you copy the SQL out from your code and run it in something like SQL Server Management Studio, does it work without error there?

Comment: The query executes fine if executed from SQL Server Manager. I should be connected to correct DB, because `SELECT`queries works fine.

Comment: @Steven In your examples, you're INSERTing into `dbo.nokernok_kommentarer`, but SELECTing from `nokernok_skoler`. Can you successfully SELECT from dbo.nokernok_kommentarer?