# This error keeps happening every time. What should I do?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have started working on a cash voucher project. When I click the Submit button, a pop-up box shows up and says "Invalid Object voucher_table".
What should I do??

```
private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlcn = new SqlConnection(con);
        sqlcn.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO voucher_table(customerID, planName, days, planAmount, validFrom, validTo, amountInWords, date, rupees) values(@customerID, @planName, @days, @planAmount, @validFrom, @validTo, @amountInWords, @date, @rupees)", sqlcn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", customerID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planName", planName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@days", days.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planAmount", planAmount.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@validFrom", validFrom.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@validTo", validTo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amountInWords", amountInWordsTextBox1.Text + amountInWordsTextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rupees", rupees.Text);

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Voucher Created Successfully");
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select max(primaryNo) from voucher_table", sqlcn);
                SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr1.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Voucher No is '" + dr1.GetInt32(0) + "'Your Voucher is Created Successfully!");
                    Voucher_Successful success = new Voucher_Successful();
                    success.ShowDialog();
                }
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Occured... Voucher Not Created");
            }
            sqlcn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

EDIT: [Image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSiLV.png)

[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grt93.png)

EDIT: The answer found:
I added Initial Catalog:My Cash Voucher; in app.config and the problem resolved.

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Comment: Did you select the correct database in your connection string?

Comment: The error means the table doesn't exist in that database. You're probably connecting to the wrong database, or the table hasn't been created yet

Comment: Yes, I did select the correct database. It was <connectionStrings>
  <add name="mydb" connectionString="Data Source=.\AARYANPC2019;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: You should *always* create connections in a `using` block, otherwise the connection remains open until the GC collects it, possibly hours later. Each time you got an exception you leaked an open connection. Using `finally` isn't enough either, as `finally` can be skipped in some extreme case while `using` is not

Comment: @AaryanKh2007 the error is pretty clear - the table isn't there. Either it's the wrong database or the table doesn't exist. Or you don't have permissions to read and write to it (although I think that would cause a different error)

Comment: then what should i do?? plz help

Comment: @AaryanKh2007 have you tried running the same query, in the same database in SSMS?

Comment: `then what should i do??` make sure you use the correct database. Make sure the table is there. Make sure you connect to the *correct server* - did you really create a named instance on your PC called `.\AARYANPC2019` ? What happened to the default instance?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because the default instance crashed the pc

Comment: No it didn't. Your PC has a problem to begin with. You need to fix it. Hundreds of thousands of servers work as default instances, if there was a problem a *lot* of very big companies would have noticed. And MS would be bankrupt

Comment: As for the actual problem, the table simply isn't there and you may be connecting to the wrong instance too - you may have created the table in one instance but try to connect to another

Comment: The answer found: I added Initial Catalog:My Cash Voucher; in app.config and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue in your connection string as the error message clearly mention that the table name not found. there is a simple way to check connectivity. Just do the following

[image: check connection string]

No need to add a connection, use it just to test it. Once tested click cancel button to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not in the correct database (ie. the SQL command doesn't find voucher_table).
Check if voucher_table really exists in the database that you connected to.

I have found a similar problem to yours, you might find help there too: [SQL Server: invalid object name in query execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307641/sql-server-invalid-object-name-in-query-execution)